# Execute terminal commands in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, subprocess, raspbian

I am on a Raspberry Pi, and I am using a program called `fswebcam`, which allows you to take pictures with a webcam.

```
~$ fswebcam image.jpg
```

That command if entered in terminal takes a picture and saves it to your computer, however I want to build a simple python program that can access the terminal and execute that same command as I have listed above.

I have tried to `import os` and use `os.system('fswebcam image.jpg')` But it isn't working for me.

How can I have python execute terminal commands?

Comment: Please show some actual code you've tried and the error you got.

Comment: is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: @KevinGuan Probably. However the `subprocess` module is preferred.

Comment: Terminological note: a _terminal_ is a device (probably a virtual one shown in the window) used by interactive programs, most notably an interactive command interpreter (called _shell_ in Unix jargon). `os.system` usually uses the same shell but in non-interactive mode. So, `fswebcam image.jpg` is a _shell command_, but it isn't related to _terminal_.

Comment: what is `type fswebcam` or `command -v fswebcam`? (type the commands in the shell)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["fswebcam", "image.jpg"])
```

Comment: if `os.system('fswebcam image.jpg')` doesn't work (e.g., because `fswebcam` is an alias that is available only in the interactive shell) then `subprocess.Popen(["fswebcam", "image.jpg"])` won't help either. To wait for the command to finish, use `subprocess.check_call()` instead `Popen()`.